Connection refused to keycloak's configuration uri from my gateway spring boot service (both running on docker)
It seems my gateway service is failing to resolve the host of my keycloak realm configuration uri (both are running locally on docker)
I am able to see the page via browser on "http://localhost:8080/realms/Events/.well-known/openid-configuration"
Caused by exception in gateway service logs:
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://keycloak:8080/realms/Events/.well-known/openid-configuration": Connection refused
my docker-compose.yml is:
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16
    container_name: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: eventsadmin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_pass
      POSTGRES_DB: eventsdb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - eventslistingapp_default

  eureka-server:
    image: eureka-server
    build: ./configuration/eureka-server
    container_name: eureka-server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    networks:
      - eventslistingapp_default

  config-server:
    image: config-server
    build: ./configuration/config-server
    container_name: config-server
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=default
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
    networks:
      - eventslistingapp_default

  gateway:
    image: gateway
    build: ./configuration/gateway
    container_name: gateway
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
      - config-server
    networks:
      - eventslistingapp_default

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - KC_DB=postgres
      - KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres/eventsdb
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak_user
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=keycloak_user
      - KC_DB_SCHEMA=keycloak
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    command:
      - start-dev
    networks:
      - eventslistingapp_default

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    container_name: portainer
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - portainer_data:/data
    networks:
      - eventslistingapp_default

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  portainer_data:

networks:
  eventslistingapp_default:
    driver: bridge
    external: true

my gateway/application.yml is:
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
    web-application-type: reactive
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:http://config-server:8888
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: http://keycloak:8080/realms/Events/protocol/openid-connect/certs
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://keycloak:8080/realms/Events
        registration:
          gateway:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: gateway
            client-secret: SPQByrPTSpwEfDaZVYwIQym5BGm7GUpB
            scope: openid
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/

server:
  port: 80

I also have this configuration class in gateway service:
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange(auth -> auth.anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        http.csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable);
        return http.build();
    }
}

I have created a realm in keycloak named 'Events'
SSL-Required is set to none in realm settings
I have created a client named 'gateway'
Not sure if it's relevant but my machine is macbook pro M3
Am I missing any configuration?
I have also tried other hosts instead of keycloak:8080 like host.docker.internal, localhost, 127.0.0.1, the keycloak's container IpAddress but still getting the same issue
I am expecting that my gateway can make a successfull connection to localhost:8080/realms/Events/.well-known/openid-configuration
PS: First time posting a question so let me know if I missed any info!

Can you call http://keycloak:8080/realms/Events/.well-known/openid-configuration from your CLI? Can you call it from your CLI with the Gateway IP of your network eventslistingapp_default?

Yes, using the below steps I get a successful response:
$ docker exec -it eb475b2fe6c7 sh
$ curl http://keycloak:8080/realms/Events/.well-known/openid-configuration
